# What is the plural of "corpus callosum"?

Tags: grammatical-number, latin

The Latin "corpus callosum" is also the common English name for a bundle of nerve fibers that connect the hemispheres of the cerebrum.  Should the plural be the odd-sounding "corpa callosa" or the clumsy "corpus callosums"?

Comment: In English, it is the latter. To confirm or refute that assertion, you may wish to search corpora of relevant medical journals and compare usage of both terms.

Comment: The Latin plural is *corpora callosa*.

Answer (score 5):

**Corpora callosa** is the plural form.

See where it says "*plural*" [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corpus%20callosum) or [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/corpus%20callosum).

Answer (score 3):

You almost had it right: it should be several *corp**ora** callosa* in Latin. If you are transplanting the whole thing into English without naturalizing it as in this case indeed applies, then just leave it like that.

The Latin *-a* plural is for neuters, not just ones like *callosum > callosa* and *datum > data* in the second declension but also neuters in other declensions, like  *nomen > nomina* and *carmen > carmina* in the third or *cornu > cornua* in the fourth.

But *corpus* although neuter is not in the second declension, so it does not become “corpa”.

Rather, it is in the third-declension where the neuter *corpus/-**or**is* is  to be found, and so its plural is *corp**or**a* — even in (scholarly) English use.

Some people do say *corpuses* in English, which is perfectly normal and fine, but if you are going to use the full Latin phrase as you are doing here, you can’t cut corners by using English inflections in one place and Latin ones in another.

Other third-declension neuters you might recognize include:

- *opus > opera*
- *genus > genera*
- *tempus > tempora*

We don’t use *tempora* much in English, but it did gave us our adjective  *temporal*.  So you can find vestiges of the third declension  showing up in derived forms in English, like in English *general* and *corporal*.

Other examples of third-declension nouns giving us adjectives include *pectus/-oris* which gave us English *pectoral* and also *Venus/-eris* which gave us English *venereal*.

<sub>(Not that *Venus* is neuter; she is of course feminine. But she is third declension.)</sub>

Comment: Your inclusion of *opus/opera* urges me to say that the plural of *magnum opus* is *magna opera* - just in case anyone might be wondering.

Comment: Is _collosum/-a_, rather than _callosum/-a_ intentional? (And if so, why?)